# Do i need husbands permission to work

Tags: sharia, islamic-basis, work, wife, husband

Salaam, I have been dishearnted with Islam's take on working women. Why does a women need the husband's permission to work and wear is the stipulated clear proof that husband's have the right to prevent women from working even though many situations women have been put through contradict that.

I have witnessed countless times women who suffered severely because the husband prevents the wife to work even though it's 100% permitted for women to have the right to earn their own income. And if Islam promotes equality and equal rights why should the husband have the final say on her right to work? Where is the evidence or the authenticity of this or is Scholars enabling men more power over their women than stated.

Comment: This question seems to think such evidence is needed when the fact is that women working in such large quantities is a modern phenomenon. Why would there be clear evidence of something when it was never common until today? But, there can be plenty of derived evidence.

Answer (score -2):

The main reason is for the safety of the woman.
If there is no immediate threat there should be no reason for the man to stop the woman.

Also, Prophet Muhammad (SAWS) said on his last khutbah (the final one before his death), that the best man among you is the one who treats his wife the best.

This does not only include your wife but every other person that is connected to you, that depends upon you some or the other way.

Coming back, the main mistake you have made here is you have taken the scholars too seriously, what the scholar says is one mans opinion, doesn't have to be right, but you know what is always right.

The Holy Quraan. any scripture sent by Allah (SWT) is the truth.

instead of consulting scholars who are after all humans and hence inherently flawed, I advise you read the holy Quraan, the answers found therein will satisfy and comfort you.

If your man is stopping you from working for any other reason other that concern for your safety, Allah (SWT) will bring him to account for this.

May Allah make things easier for you.

I am sorry if i haven't been able to answer all your questions but i'd say you read the Quraan and find out instead of believing me, or anyone for that matter.